# Form button to redirect user to specific page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a function on a page which takes a user to another page if the action is equal to 'add'. I now want to create a button which will do this for me without typing &action=add into the url.

The function looks like this:

```
 function consultants_page() {
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'add') {
       require( get_template_directory() . '/settings/pages/consultant_add.php' ); 
    }else {
        require( get_template_directory() . '/settings/pages/consultant.php');
    }
}
```

I then need to amend this button to link to this function, but it isn't currently working..

```
<form method="get" action="add">
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="add" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Add"></p>
</form>
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will send the variable "action" to the url:

```
<form method="get" >
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="action" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="add"></p>
 </form>
```

with your html you where sending `add?add=Add`.

Your php code should get the variable with `$_GET["action"]`.

Answer (score 0):

use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, that way the values will not appear in the url.

```
function consultants_page() {
    if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'add') {
   require( get_template_directory() . '/settings/pages/consultant_add.php' ); 
    }else {
    require( get_template_directory() . '/settings/pages/consultant.php');
    }
}
```

html

```
<form method="post" action="add">
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="add" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Add"></p>
</form>
```

don't forget to sanitize user input.